# cordova_not_available in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

Home.ts

```
 import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
         public camera:Camera
        ) {}

    getImage(){
      var control = this;
      const options :CameraOptions = {
        quality: 70,
        destinationType : this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
      }

      this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {
        control.shopPhoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      },
      err => {
        alert('error: ' + err)
      });
    }
```

package.json

```
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "your usage message"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {}
    },
```

But i got error "error: cordova_not_available" on mobile device.
even i install cordova.

i installed Genymotion for android testing but its not working there.

Please help me.

[Error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsVAl.png)

Answer (score 1):

`ionic cordova run android --device` try this.

Don't forget, you will have to test this on a real device or emulator/simulator.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

**1) Open First your Emulator/Simulator**

**2) Run this**

```
ionic cordova emulate android -c
```

(**-c** flag it´s for activate Console debug)

that command should be connect directly your app build to your Emulator/Simulator
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/emulate/

**3) Test Again**

hopefully it will help you to grab more information about the error. :D

PD. Make Sure you have integrate the Native Cordova integration when you start the project

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply add this line to the index in head, I lost a day for this

```
<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```